# Datatables sorting on table with varying number of columns

Tags: sorting, datatables

I have a table which will have a varying number of columns, but one column will always be present, albeit in a different position every time depending on the data to be displayed (eg it could be column 2, column 3, column 4 etc). This column I want to be set as the initial sorted column and sorted DESC. The data displayed in this column is a checkbox and as a result the data-sort attribute is being used to sort the data, with 1 for checked, 0 for unchecked.

What I need to be able to do is the following and I am not sure how to achieve it on a column that could be in any position (ie have a varying index). If there was a static number of columns then this would be fine as I would be able to set the options accordingly knowing the column index as follows:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "order": [[ 2, 'desc' ]]
});
```

But as the column would be a different number depending on the table content then I need to reference the column accordingly. I need to:

- Set initial sorting column as this column;
- Set the sort order as DESC.

<< UNTESTED >> - I also need to change the data-sort value accordingly (0 or 1) when the checkbox is checked / unchecked. I haven't tested as yet but if an answer is available I would appreciate the feedback - does datatables pick up changes to the data-sort attribute and adjust the sorting accordingly?  If not, what can I pass to datatables to re-sort after the data-sort attribute has been changed?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

As I could not find any way to achieve this using datatables I have done the following:

**The HTML**

For columns that need to be sorted add a `data-order` attribute with 'asc' or 'desc'.

```
<th data-order="desc">Column Heading</th>
```

**The Scripting**

```
var ordering = [];
var theTable = jQuery( '#example' ).DataTable();
theTable.columns().every( function( i ) {
    var header = this.header();
    if ( jQuery( header ).is( '[data-order]' ) ) {
        var dataOrder = jQuery( header ).attr( 'data-order' );
        var theOrder = [ i, dataOrder ];
        ordering.push( theOrder );
    }
});
if( ordering.length > 0 ) {
    theTable.order( ordering ).draw();
}
```